# Do we ever learn what the Prophets did to the Dominion Fleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In "[Sacrifice of Angels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_%28episode%29)", Sisko takes the Defiant into the wormhole to take out as many of the Dominion ships passing through as he can. The so-called prophets, who have other plans for Sisko (and would rather not see Bajor burned to ash) do *something* to make the Dominion armada 'disappear'—does anyone know what that something was?

Comment: Moved them in time probably. Past or present, who can say.

Comment: While the Prophets are probably unsympathetic enough to have simply dematerialized them, I personally prefer to assume they were returned to the Gamma Quadrant end of the wormhole. :-)

Comment: @That is possible, but then the prophets would have to *keep* returning them to the Gamma quadrant side (they'd keep trying to come through) and who wants to deal with that over and over?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - It's explicitly stated that they weren't sent back to the other end.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - From the script; **WEYOUN** 
   *That's impossible! Check our 
   listening posts in the Gamma 
   Quadrant.*

     **DAMAR** 
   *They're not there either.*

Comment: @Richard: I had interpreted that as meaning that the listening posts themselves were missing, but I suppose it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @Xantec: seems to me the Founders would keep sending fleets through either way, though perhaps after three or four of them went missing they would give up. :-)  I kind of assumed that the Prophets closed the Gamma quadrant end of the wormhole so that nobody could get through without permission, but now that I think about it I can't really justify that.  Wishful thinking, I guess. :-)

Comment: Kind of spoilerish title.  (Cue someone to question whether we should worry about spoilers for fifteen year old events.   Answer: yes)

Comment: They were sent back to a previous time in the Gamma Quadrant. In fact, they were the group that founded The Dominion. ;-P

Comment: @HarryJohnston - There's a quote from the showrunners that the Prophets just "stopped" the Dominion from sending additional ships but there's no mention of how many times they tried.

Comment: “The so-called prophets” — ***INFIDEL***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't know, nor is it ever stated within the main canon (TV, Films) what happened to the Jem'Hadar fleet.

The [script notes](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/530.txt) state:

> The approaching Dominion reinforcement fleet has begun to be hit by
>   some sort of strange energy jolts that crackles from ship to ship. And
>   as we watch, **the ships seem to vanish until the entire fleet has
>   disappeared.**
>
> ...
>
> **GARAK:** *Then where did they go?*
>
> Sisko begins to understand what the wormhole aliens have done.
>
> **SISKO:** *Wherever they went, I don't think they're coming back.*

And that's literally your lot.

---

Moving down the canon scale, the fleet reappears in the future in the Star Trek Online mission "[The 2800](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Cardassian_Struggle)", later retitled as the "Cardassian Struggle".

In this mission, The Dominion fleet suddenly materialises around 40 years into the future and proceeds to board DS9 and take the crew hostage. It's up to you, the player to liberate that crew with the minimal loss of life.

Comment: I hope the player at least has a decisive technological advantage over the 40-year-old Dominion fleet? :-)

Comment: that depends how much money you've spent in the game :D

Comment: @HarryJohnston- It was a pretty large fleet, and they weren't expected in the least. So while they might have a technological advantage, they'd have a distinct numerical disadvantage. I think the Dominion troops weren't even initially aware of the temporal disparity though.

Comment: @Derek eh, you cant really "buy" better weapons, really only cooler looking ships.

Comment: @HarryJohnston and yes in the mission they still have a fleet close to 1000 ships, so even a supped up DS9 cant handle 1000 ships on its own (it may have been 100s, but i think it was a very large fleet)

Answer (score -2):

I have no evidence but I’d always hoped that they were flung far back in time and continued to Qonos effectively becoming the Hur’q. And when they realised that they couldn’t return, couldn’t breed and couldn’t create anymore white they effectively became the BREEN and waited for the time when they could become useful again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Without evidence this is just a personal theory; please post answers based on what is known in canon and from the creators.  You might want to take the [tour] to learn how the site works.