# Why did the Prophets choose a human?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Why would the prophets choose a human to be an emissary for them? Wouldn't it have been easier to choose a Bajoran, someone they could relate to?

Comment: The Sisko is of Bajor.

Comment: @Valorum - I see. I thought they would have chosen someone born on Bajor, and by all accounts a Bajoran.

Comment: The Sisko *is* of Bajor.

Comment: @Valorum - Sure. The Sisko is of Bajor.

Comment: But seriously, they chose Sarah Sisko because she could then be the mother of Ben Sisko, the Emissary of the prophets.

Comment: @Valorum - Why her though? Why not a Bajoran female?

Comment: I think what "The Sisko is of Bajor" alludes to is that despite his species, his heart belongs to Bajor, which is what really matters.

Comment: Consider for a moment how almost any Bajoran would have acted on first meeting the Prophets (most likely falling on their face in worship and then actively misunderstanding what the Prophets meant to a much greater degree than Sisko did), compared to how Sisko reacted (he took a remarkably analytical approach even for a Starfleet officer, trying to relatively politely have a rather frank conversation with them to figure out who they were and what was going on). There’s no clear evidence in the series to indicate it, but this difference is probably a contributing factor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[You are linear. It limits you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJ33e9BK9aU).**

The simplest explanation is that they chose for one of their number to inhabit Sarah Sisko because they had already (in the future) observed that her son, Ben Sisko was the first to enter their Celestial Temple and become the Emissary of the Prophets. By taking over her body, they could ensure that he would have the powers necessary to act as their instrument in the war against the Pah Wraiths.

So why a human? Because Ben Sisko was the Emissary and was a human. Note that this explanation only makes sense if you're [not subjectively bound by time](https://youtu.be/q2nNzNo_Xps).

Comment: In the finale his wife was pregnant, would his future child also be an Emissary as well, with powers?

Comment: @EmpressSvetlana - A potential Emissary, if we believe the nonsense in the EU novel "*The Soul Key*"

Comment: This can be supported by the numerous prophecies surrounding the Emissary. 

-In the series opening episode "The Emissary", Kai Opaka says to Sisko, after feeling his Pah, "Ironic, one who does not wish to be among us is to be the Emissary."
-Former Vedek Yarka comes to DS9 to warn Sisko about Trakor's Third and Fourth Prophecies, which both center on the Emissary dealing with terrible trials in the episode "Destiny"

Answer (score 8):

The DS9 episode [Accession](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/489.htm) offers us the only real hint here. A Bajoran named [Akorem Laan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Akorem_Laan) is literally sent from the past to the present and believes he is the Emissary. The Prophets state otherwise (note: except for Sisko and Akorem, these are not other characters talking, but The Prophets using their forms)

> KIRA: The Sisko taught us that for you, what was, can never be again.
> AKOREM: If the D'jarras belong in the past, why did you send me into the future?
> ODO: For the Sisko.
> SISKO: For me?
> AKOREM: **You're saying that he's your Emissary?**
> BASHIR: **He is the Sisko.**
> (snip)
> OPAKA: Why? Why do you stay here?
> SISKO: Because I still have questions.
> OPAKA: We are of Bajor.
> SISKO: What does that mean?
> OPAKA: **You are of Bajor.**

You'll note that they refer to both themselves and Sisko as being "of Bajor", despite none of them actually being Bajoran.

If you watch the whole series, you'll repeatedly see Sisko start to grow to be more and more Bajoran and gradually accepts the role of Emissary. It's not that they picked a human, it's that they literally wanted Benjamin Sisko ("He is **the** Sisko"). We're never told why him specifically (possibly due to his confrontation of the [Pah-wraiths](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pah-wraith) in the series finale), but they went to great lengths to both ensure his birth and keep him at Bajor (most notably [wiping out an entire Dominion fleet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104184/62709)).

Comment: Love how he never even tries to correct them on that naming thing.  Like "Hey, My dad is a Sisko, my son is a Sisko, my wife was a Sisko.  Call me 'Ben'".